# Can anybody help me with the looping of my program(GAUSS SEIDEL METHOD)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iteration

The user will input 2 equations then solving for its iteration (sorry for my English). The problem that the loop is not being executed. The code should break out when the value of et is less than the value of g.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

 long double g=0.0010;
 int main()
 {

    long double xe,ye,et,k,x,y,x1,x2,y1,y2,c1,c2,a,b;
    //for the input
    cout<<"EQUATION 1:\n";
    cout<<"Input your desired numerical coefficient for x:"<<endl;
    cin>>x1;
    cout<<"Input your desired numerical coefficient for y:"<<endl;
    cin>>y1;
    cout<< "Input your constant's value:"<<endl;
    cin>>c1;
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"EQUATION 2:\n";
    cout<<"Input your desired numerical coefficient for x:"<<endl;
    cin>>x2;
    cout<<"Input your desired numerical coefficient for y:"<<endl;
    cin>>y2;
    cout<< "Input your constant's value:"<<endl;
    cin>>c2;
    system("CLS");
    //to show the equation made
    cout<<"Your EQUATION 1 is:\n"<<x1<<"x + <"<<y1<<"y)"<<" = "<<c1<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Your EQUATION 2 is:\n"<<x2<<"x + ("<<y2<<"y)"<<" = "<<c2<<endl<<endl;

    //first value of x and y
    x=c1/x1;
    y=(c2)/y2;
    //show the values
    cout<<"\nx="<<x<<endl;
    cout<<"y="<<y<<endl;
    //this is where the iteration starts
    for(k=1;g>et;k++)
{

    a=(c1+y)/x1;
    b=(c2-x)/y2;
    xe=((a-y)/a)*-1;
    ye=((b-x)/b);
    et=((xe+ye)/2);
    cout<<"k="<<k;
    cout<<"\nx="<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"y="<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"\nxe="<<xe;
    cout<<"\nye="<<ye;
    cout<<"\net="<<et<<endl;
    }


    return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using

```
while (std::abs(et) > g)
```

or something like that instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use more whitespace to make it easier to see what you're doing. Seriously, this is the main problem.

The termination condition should be when the *maximum* error is below a certain limit, because then all variables have converged "enough." As it is, you're taking the sum of the rates of change, which may cause premature termination if they happen to be of opposite sign, or uneven degrees of convergence otherwise.

Negating `xe` does not help because in the general case they can overshoot and reverse sign.

Comment: et should be the average of xe and ye.

Comment: @BossJeric I misunderstood the variables… please, use more whitespace and comments. This answer is updated, should be insightful now.